# Scroll a div to a certain class name horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a navigation bar with the following structure in my page. I have already written the jQuery to add a class for the "Selected" tab when I entered the page and identifying that with some ID to indicate which page we are on. This looks fine on a desktop.

However, when I am viewing with mobile, like when I am on the page of the last tab (Tab E), the navbar will still position at the beginning of the bar (Tab A). I would like to make it scroll horizontally on mobile when I come to those specific pages.

Can anyone suggest how I can do it with jQuery? Thank you so much.

```js
if ($('#pageE').length) {
  $('.navBar .tab').removeClass('selected');
  $('.navBar .tabE').addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navBar .tab {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.navBar .tab a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navBar .tab.selected a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navBar">
  <div class="tab tabA">
    <a href="pageA">Tab A</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabB">
    <a href="pageB">Tab B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabC">
    <a href="pageC">Tab C</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabD">
    <a href="pageD">Tab D</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabE selected">
    <a href="pageE">Tab E</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to use [scrollLeft](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/#scrollLeft2) or [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) if you want a sort of smooth animation.

```
var selectedPosition = $(".tab.selected").offset().left;
$(".navBar").scrollLeft(selectedPosition); // without animation.

$('.navBar').animate({scrollLeft: selectedPosition}, 400) // a solution with an animation
```

```js
if ($('#pageE').length) {
  $('.navBar .tab').removeClass('selected');
  $('.navBar .tabE').addClass('selected');


  var selectedPosition = $(".tab.selected").offset().left;
  $(".navBar").scrollLeft(selectedPosition); // without smooth.
  // $('.navBar').animate({scrollLeft: selectedPosition}, 400) // a solution with smooth
}
```

```css
.navBar {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .navBar .tab {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }

  .navBar .tab a {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navBar .tab.selected a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 5px;
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navBar">
  <div class="tab tabA">
    <a href="pageA">Tab A</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabB">
    <a href="pageB">Tab B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabC">
    <a href="pageC">Tab C</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabD">
    <a href="pageD">Tab D</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab tabE">
    <a href="pageE">Tab E</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="pageE"></div>
```

Comment: It's working now! Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

For horizontal scroll, you can use `scrollIntoView()` method

jQuery

```
$("#elementID")[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
});
```

JavaScript

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementID"); 
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) :

```
$(container).scrollTo(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
  scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes... scrollTop can't scroll horizontally. but anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Ya. I forgot to change scrollTop to scrollLeft. I pasted this snippet from one of my code so forgot to change. Though, glad that you got the answer.